# How can I make title quotations use single quotes?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to display all titles in my bibliography / references using single quotes.

In other words,

```
Gordon E Moore, “Cramming more com- ponents onto integrated circuits” (1965) 38(8) Electronics 114.
```

should be

```
Gordon E Moore, `Cramming more com- ponents onto integrated circuits' (1965) 38(8) Electronics 114.
```

I'm basing my style off earlier work by another developer.  In the original style, he wrote:

```
% AGLC likes to use single quotes everywhere, not double quotes.
\renewrobustcmd{\mkbibquote}[1]{`#1'}
```

I can only assume that this was intended to force teh use of single quotes, but it doesn't appear to be working.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: The correct way is to use `csquotes` with `biblatex` and set the language and quoting style accordingly.

Comment: If you post a minimal(!) example, I or someone else is likely to give better advice.  As it is, your based-on-earlier-work style might override any potentially useful advice (or might not; it's hard to tell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `csquotes` to set the quoting style.  The `british` style has single rather than double quotes (at the outer level):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Moore,
  author =   {Moore, Gordon E.},
  title =    {Cramming more components onto integrated circuits},
  journal =  {Electronics},
  year =     1965,
  volume =   38,
  number =   8,
  pages =    114
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Moore}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can limit this to the bibliography by using `\setquotestyle{british}` just before `\printbibliography`.