Avoid << >> in article citation
I'm writing my thesis, and I'm having some problem with bibliography.
I'm using this configuration:
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

An average citation looks like this:
@article{general_article,
    author = {Egerstedt, Magnus and Martini, Simone and Cao, Ming and Camlibel, Kanat and Bicchi, Antonio},
    title = {Interacting with Networks: How Does Structure Relate to Controllability in Single-Leader, Consensus Networks?}, 
    journal = {IEEE Control Systems Magazine}, 
    year = {2012},
  volume={32},
  number={4},
  pages={66-73},
}

The result is smth like:
M. Egerstedt, S. Martini, M. Cao, K. Camlibel e A. Bicchi, ≪Inte-
racting with Networks: How Does Structure Relate to Controllabi-
lity in Single-Leader, Consensus Networks?≫ IEEE Control Systems
Magazine, vol. 32, n. 4, pp. 66–73, 2012

My questions is, how do I customize the appearance of the citation? My supervisor says that no <<>> is generally used in citation, yet I can't find how to customize the apparence, nor a style that avoids them.
Thanks for the help!

What language is your document set to be in? The IEEE use quote marks for titles, and they will pick up the locale

I set the document in Italian

Possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116121/ would work, but then with style=english instead of british.

Thanks a lot, that works, is there a way to avoid them at all? No quotes for article name?

@AlessandroPetitti The IEEE use quotes for titles - that's why the style sets them up ;) You can modify the style in place, but that's a different question

Oh I got it. Which would be the way to do that?

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 if you need to get rid of the quotation marks.
